# Process dies after SIGINT signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I don't understand what is happening here, I have a parent process which handles the SIGINT signal and then makes a child. What I expect when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is that both processes will print "SIGINT received" and then continue but it turns out that the parent process dies after receiving SIGINT but the child is still there. I can't understand that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void handler (int sig) {
  printf("SIGINT received\n");
}

void child() {
  while (1) {
    printf("I'm the child\n");
    sleep(1);
  }

  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct sigaction act;

  memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

  act.sa_handler = &handler;
  // Link SIGINT with the handler
  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

  // Create child
  if (fork() == 0) child();

  wait(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

An example of execution:

```
$ ./test_signals
I'm the child
^CSIGINT received
I'm the child
SIGINT received
$ I'm the child
I'm the child
```

So both processes handle SIGINT but the parent dies while the child continues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent process is blocked in the main function and upon receiving the signal, handles it and returns from the call to `wait` with an error.

The child is just looping in the `while` handling SIGINT. When handled code returns where it was (probably blocked in sleep) and it continues to loop.

That code may illustrates what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

void handler (int sig) {
  printf("SIGINT received %d\n",getpid());
}

void child() {
  while (1) {
    printf("I'm the child\n");
    sleep(1);
  }

  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct sigaction act;

  memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));

  act.sa_handler = &handler;
  // Link SIGINT with the handler
  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

  // Create child
  if (fork() == 0) child();

  int r = wait(NULL);
  if (r==-1 && errno==EINTR) printf("signal probably received in parent\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Be aware that calling `printf` in a signal handler is forbidden.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that the reception of a signal interrupts `wait` but I figured out that if I use `signal` instead of `sigaction`, the parent is still waiting and doesn't exit. Is it because my system's implementation of `signal` acts like `sigaction` with the flag SA_RESTART positioned?

Comment: Yes different implementations of `signal` exists... This function is considered as obsolete for many reasons among this one. Always prefer `sigaction`.